# replacing string with '~'

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I am wondering if there is a simple way using sed or awk to replace a string with a '~'. For example, I am hoping to replace any character that is not a letter with '~', so that this

```
0EEEEEETTS-EEEEE->TTSBHHHHHHHHHHHH<<->>GGGEEEEETTEE->TTSBTGGGT<>TT<EEEEEE--S00
```

becomes

```
~EEEEEETTS~EEEEE~~TTSBHHHHHHHHHHHH~~~GGGEEEEETTEE~~TTSBTGGGT~~TT~EEEEEE~~S~~
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the job `tr` exists to do.

```
$ tr -c '[:alpha:]\n' '~' < file
~EEEEEETTS~EEEEE~~TTSBHHHHHHHHHHHH~~~~~GGGEEEEETTEE~~TTSBTGGGT~~TT~EEEEEE~~S~~
```